# Migrations doesn't affect database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, migration

I am new to Rails and I am facing the following problem. There were different tables in the existing project schema such as questionnaire, test, answers, questions, etc. But they did not have the columns of the creation date and the update date, and there were no models and views yet. So I decided to delete them and recreate them. Unfortunately I did it directly through the pgAdmin. Then I recreated each model with a scaffold generator. Everything was going fine until I got to the Questions model. For this model, I forgot to delete the table from the database, which I decided to do. But when I returned to the terminal and tried again to migrate the creation of the question table, I came across the same error message that the table already exists. Moreover, in the schema, I found that all tables manually removed from the database are still present.

**What I tried:**
I wrote migrations to drop tables. Migrations go through, tables disappear from the schema. Then I tried to write again table creation migrations, they are also started and tables are added to the schema, but they are not created in the database itself. But the application is still accessing the database, retrieving data, inserting it (into other tables that I have not touched on).
How can I return everything to the original? Migrations do not work in the project and I do not understand how to fix it. And I would not really like to dump the database, since it contains a lot of data.

Also in the project there are old migrations of test creation, test results, etc., which I deleted manually through the PG Admin. Should I delete them?

[db/migrate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qaASZ.png)

Comment: It would be best practice to make any schema changes through migrations, not by making direct edits with pgAdmin or psql. When you make changes to the schema outside of the migrations you risk failures when run migrations. Also, active record keeps a record of migrations it has run in a table called schema_migrations. If you see modifications to the schema after running migrations, that means it was able to modify the database. Are you sure you're looking at the correct environment you ran the migrations against? Rails typically has 3 databases: _test, _development, and _production

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a bug. The problem was that the project turns out to be using docker (did not fully understand what it is). But as I understand it, for any update of the project, it must be reloaded through 4 commands in the terminal. Therefore, migrations did not go through the terminal. they had to be done by the docker himself. I expected to see the error logs right in the terminal, and they were issued by docker. I should have connected to the docker logs and read errors from there. There, he swore in plain text about the impossibility of migrating due to the lack of tables. I rolled back migrations to the state before the problem, removed migrations conflicting with the current state of the database and created new ones, according to the rails conventions. In the end, everything worked.